# atoi(textline[c]) iterating through getline?

Tags: c++, getline, atoi

I'm new to C++, what can I do to perform something like:

```
getline(textfile, txtline);
int i = 0;
while (textline[i] != ' ') // Until space
{
    if (isdigit(txtline[i]) == true) 
        int n = atoi(txtline[i]);
        // Then code to use n
    i++;
}
```

`atoi()` is generating an error, but am I not just passing a char to it?

Here's the full error:

```
myqueens.cpp:32:11: error: no matching function for call to 'atoi'
                int n = atoi(txtline[i]);
                        ^~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:132:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'value_type' (aka 'char') to 'const char *' for 1st argument; take the address of the argument with &
int      atoi(const char *);
         ^
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to note what kind of error is generated (compiler, runtime, logical) and the error message if there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that atoi() expects a string (i.e. char*). So, you can get the message after debugging: cannot convert from 'const char' to 'char[]'.

So, if you want to convert textline[i] to int, you can use

```
int n = textline[i] - '0';
```

Comment: hmm I get 'Segmentation fault: 11' error here when I try to then use the n for the upper bound of a for loop.

Comment: @AustinMW then you have a problem in the for loop, because GAVD's solution is correct, assuming ascii file input. Take care that your data file isn't encoded in some form of unicode.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, you have some typos in your code (`txtline` instead of `textline`).

You also have an index bounds error: if `textline` doesn't contain a space at all, `i` will fall off of the valid indices in `textline`, so you'll be accessing invalid data.

As for the error with `atoi`: the [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) function attempts to convert a C-style (null-terminated) string to an integer value. Your usage therefore is wrong: you're passing a `char`, but `atoi` requires a *pointer* to a `char` (in this case, a pointer a char that is interpreted as a C-style string). What exactly is the code you posted supposed to do?

If you *need* to use `atoi`, I would advise doing some more research into C-style strings. If you *don't*, I would advise using something more C++-ish, like [`stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream), to get integers out of strings.

Comment: hmm I hadn't thought of that, but I know from my file that the getline will always have a space. oops, also fixed the txtline, that wasn't in my code just when i rewrote it here.

Comment: Is this actually what is causing the particular error I have though or is it just something else that could happen? I added a condition for in the while loop of: && (i < 40) and it still errors.

Comment: the code is eventually supposed to take a forsyth notation line like "2Q5/5Q2/3Q4/Q7/7Q/4Q3/6Q1/1Q6 w - - 0 1" and convert it to a 0x7 square where queens are 1's and empty spaces are 0's. Is there a simple way to convert to int without pointers? I haven't got to learning about them yet.